# Why Sonar rules java:S5542 does not allow to use PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128 algorithm?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, sha256

I'm building secure data storeage app. I need to encrypt and decrpyt with a password. I choose "**PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128**" algrotihm for it.

Sonar rule (java:S5542) doesn't allow to use **PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128**. As far as I know PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128 is secure enough. I can't find significant information about this. Isn't it secure enough? Thanks.

Here is the [Sonar Rule](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/1782).
Here is my wrapped code:

```
String ALGORITM = "PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_128";
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
int ITERATE_COUNT = 65536;

byte[] iv = new byte[16];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);

byte[] salt = new byte[32];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);


IvParameterSpec ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, ITERATE_COUNT, ivParamSpec);

AlgorithmParameters algorithmParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(ALGORITM);
algorithmParameters.init(pbeParamSpec);

String spec = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(algorithmParameters.getEncoded()));

PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray());
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITM);
SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec);

AlgorithmParameters algorithmParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(ALGORITM);
algorithmParameters.init(Base64.getDecoder().decode(spec));

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITM);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, algorithmParameters);

return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that PBE part of the algorithm is insecure, because of the low iteration count (similar reason for DES to be insecure). However I think insecurity is purely theoretic. Information is indeed hard to find though i hope [this](https://www.appmarq.com/public/tqi,1039022,CWE-916Cryptographic-HashAvoid-using-Insecure-PBE-Iteration-Count) and [this](https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.semantic.cpp.weak_cryptographic_hash_insecure_pbe_iteration_count) will be helpful.

Comment: In one of that link says ITERATE_COUNT sould >1000. I choose a higher number. I suppose we can say its safer.